# Change one URL variable on re-submission

Tags: javascript, php

I have a PHP page that displays data using different variables submitted through the URL. For instance:

```
index.php?rownum=30&colnum=2&qlang=en
```

I need to give the user the ability to change the sort order.

For that I have added an HTML `<select>` with two options calling my `re_order()` function which should basically call the same URL with all parameters intact except the new sort order.

Is there an easy way to perform that or should I use a PHP session to see what parameters have been set before?

Comment: Why do you need to keep track of the previous sort order ?

Answer (score 1):

That's a task that should be handled by the client.

You can probably do something like this:

```
location.search = location.search.replace(/([&?]sort)(?:=[^&]*)?(?=&|$)/i, '$1=newvalue');
```

You can make it a reusable function:

```
function setUrlParam(searchString, param, value) {
    var rx = new RegExp('([&?]' + param + ')(?:=[^&]*)?(?=&|$)', 'i'),
        encodedVal = encodeURIComponent(value);

    return rx.test(searchString)?
        searchString.replace(rx, '$1=' + encodedVal) :
        searchString += '&' + param + '=' + encodedVal;
}


location.search = setUrlParam(location.search, 'sort', 'date');
```